# append to an array without replacing original array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I am trying to create an array based on another, but I want to keep the original array. I tried this but original array is modified, and I dont know why

```
k1=[[1,2],[3,4]]
def foo(k):
    k2=k
    for i in range(len(k2)):
        k2[i]=np.append(k2[i],i+10)
    return k2
```

Comment: In your function, `k1` is a global, not the argument `k`.  You don't do anything with `k`.  `k1` is a list of lists, but you use `np.append`, which creates an array.  Why?  `np.append` is not a good function for beginners.  It's often used wrong.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i found out what was the problem and solved like this
    k2=k[:]